# can't set jdee-server in emacs

Tags: emacs, jdee

In jdee-server's github, It says

> Copy target/jdee-bundle-${version}.jar to a directory and customize jdee-server-dir to point to the dir.

But I can't understand it. What is `target/jdee-bundle-${version}.jar`?
I install `jdee` using emacs `melpa`, it doesn't have such file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the current `pom.xml` maven file in the github repository, you can see that the `jdee-server` version number is:

```
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
```

According to the `README` file in the repository, this means the resulting jar file will be named `target/jdee-bundle-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar`. But when you build `jdee-server` following its `README` instructions, you'll get two jar files:

```
target/jdee-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
target/jdee-bundle-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar-jar-with-dependencies.jar
```

Copy both files to a directory of your choosing, then in your emacs startup file set `jdee-server-dir` to the name of that directory. For example, if the directory you choose is `/home/ttong/jdee-server`, set `jdee-server-dir` like this:

```
(setq jdee-server-dir "/home/ttong/jdee-server")
```